# Azure stream analytics anomaly function returning Exception

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

We have an IOT application. Application has to detect any sudden changes(anomaly) in the device battery voltage. We were planing on using anomaly function built into stream analytics in  azure  for accomplishing this task.

When I'm running anomaly function in stream analytics query as follows

```
SELECT    ANOMALYDETECTION(BATTERYVOLTAGE)  OVER( LIMIT DURATION(hour, 1)) 
as anomaly   FROM [IotTelemetryStream]
```

it is returning the following error message:

> unexpected error has occurred. Please open a support ticket to investigate and provide the following client request id:_______

But when running the same query after removing anomaly function  works fine.

```
SELECT   BATTERYVOLTAGE as anomaly   FROM [IotTelemetryStream]
```

I cannot find any reference for this issue any where on web so any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please send your email address in a direct message to https://twitter.com/azurestreaming ? We will reach out to you with details after that.

Comment: We were able to solve the issue ,  after contacting askasa@microsoft.com